# Export merge conflicts as Excel file

Tags: merge, visual-studio-2017, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017.
When I try to do manual merge and visual opens the Resolve Conflict window, is there any option to export that window in excel file?with the highlighted conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

By default no such an option in to export the `Resolve Conflict` window in excel...

However you can have a try for the [MS Office TFS Addin](https://github.com/miyabis/MSOfficeTFSAddin):

> Microsoft Office (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Project, Visio) add-ins
>   that assist document version control. You can invoke **TF.exe** ([TFS
>   version control command line tool TF.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc31bk2e(v=vs.120))) commands from tool bar
>   or ribbon interface of Microsoft Office. In addition, we have also
>   added the function to export VBA code. The "**Copy and resolve
>   conflict**" menu can be compared using Excel, Word using TortoiseSVN
>   or TortoiseGit if TortoiseSVN or TortoiseGit is already installed.